Is There a Closed Form for $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^n+1)}dx$?
I tried to find a general form for $a>0 , n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\Omega_n(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^n+1)} dx$$
and for even $n$ I found that
$$ \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}=-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{e^{\frac{2k+1}{n}\pi i}}{x^2+e^{\frac{2k+1}{n}\pi i-\pi i}}$$
then I got that
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2n}+1} dx=-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2k+1}{n}\pi i}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+e^{\frac{2k+1}{n}\pi i-\pi i}} dx$$
where its famous integral and by some work we can find
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2n}+1} dx=\frac{\pi}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{-a\sin\theta} \sin\left(\theta+a\cos\theta \right) \space \space, \theta=\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi$$
now by taking Laplace transform I find
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^{2n}+1)} dx=\Omega_{2n}(a)=\frac{\pi}{2an} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a \sin \theta+1}{a^2+2a \sin \theta+1}$$
which can be true for $n=0$ by limits
now for odd $n$ I tried by partial fraction, I put
$$ \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^n+1)}=\frac{A_nx+B_n}{x^2+a^2}+\frac{a_nx^{n-1}}{x^n+1}+\frac{1}{x^n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} a(n,k)x^k$$
for a numbers $A_n,B_n,a_n$ and $a(n,k)$ which is constant for $x$
then by taking integral in the interval $(0,\infty)$
and since the left side is convergent, the right side is also convergent, so we find that it must be $A_n=-a_n$ then
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^n+1)} dx=-A_n\ln a+\frac{B_n\pi}{2a} +\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} a(n,k) \csc \left(\frac{k+1}{n} \pi \right)$$
and since we found the formula for even $n$ then we need to find the constants for odd $n$ only and it's easy to show that
$$ A_{2n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{a^{2n}}{a^{4n+2}+1} , B_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{a^{4n+2}+1}$$
MY QUESTIONS
1-can we make the summation below in a simpler form?
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a \sin \theta+1}{a^2+2a \sin \theta+1}  \space \space, \theta=\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi$$
2-what is the explicit formula for $a(2n+1,k)$ ?
3-is there a way to get the same formula for $\Omega_{2n}(a)$ by partial fractions ? and what about finding $\Omega_{2n+1}(a)$ by a similar method we found $\Omega_{2n}(a)$?
4- can we get formula for $\Omega_n(a)$ by residue theorem ? I did not study complex analysis So I asked if it was possible.

Maybe could be useful for question (1): for $|a|<1$
$$\frac{1+a\sin\theta}{1+2a\sin\theta+a^2}=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^ra^{2r-1}\sin((2r-1)\theta)+\sum_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^ra^{2r}\cos(2r\theta)$$

It can be expressed by FoxH  special function.

@MariuszIwaniuk: If so, this is an analytic expression, not a closed form expression.

FWIW, for $n=1$ and $a=1,2,3,\ldots$, I inferred using Mathematica that we seem to have $\frac{k \log \left(k^2\right)+\pi }{2 \left(k^3+k\right)}$,
and for $n=2$ and the same $a$, we seem to have
$\frac{\pi}{2 \left(k^2+k\right)}$.
Continuing in this fashion we get finite sums, the number of terms of which appears to depend on $n$. If you compute enough you may be able to work out a pattern with the help of the OEIS, which you could use as a starting point for a proof.

@user64494 I didn't mention anything about closed-form in my comment?Solution is: $$\frac{\pi }{2 a}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{n}H^{3,1}_{2,3} \left[2 a \Bigg|
\begin{matrix}
(0,\frac{1}{2}), &(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \
(0,1),&(1-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}), & (\frac{1}{n},-\frac{1}{n})
\end{matrix}\right]$$

For the odd case, utilize the partial fractions below
$$\frac {2m+1}{x^{2m+1}+1}
=\frac1{x+1}+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2(1-x \cos\theta_k)}{x^2-2x \cos\theta_k+1},\>\>\>\theta_k=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2m+1}
$$
to evaluate
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{2m+1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^{2m+1}+1)} dx
=(2m+1)\Omega_{2m+1}(a)\\
=& \int_0^\infty\frac1{(x^2+a^2)(x+1)} +\sum_{k=1}^m
 \frac{2(1-x \cos\theta_k)}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2-2x \cos\theta_k+1)}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{\frac\pi{2a}+\ln a}{a^2+1}+\sum_{k=1}^m J_k(a)
\end{align}
where $J_k(a)$ can be evaluated with further partial fractions, i.e.
\begin{align}
J_k(a)= &\ \frac2{p_k(a)}\int_0^\infty \frac{a^2\cos2\theta_k+1}{x^2+a^2} +\frac{a^2+ \cos2\theta_k}{x^2-2x \cos\theta_k+1} \ dx\\
&\>\>\>\>+ \frac{2(a^2+1)\cos\theta_k}{p_k(a)}\int_0^\infty
\frac x{x^2+a^2}-\frac x{x^2-2x \cos\theta_k+1}\ dx\\
\end{align}
with $ p_k(a)=a^4+2a^2 \cos2\theta_k+1$. After some lengthy yet straightforward integration effort, one obtains the close form for the odd case
\begin{align}
&\Omega_{2m+1}(a)= \frac{\frac\pi{2a}+\ln a}{(2m+1)(a^2+1)}+\\
&\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\frac\pi a(a^2\cos2\theta_k+1)
 -2(a^2+1)\ln a\cos\theta_k 
+2(\pi-\theta_k)(a^2-1)\sin \theta_k}{(2m+1)(a^4+2a^2 \cos2\theta_k+1)}
\end{align}

very nice! thanks
